# Declare a new DAO.Recordset by (dynamic) name

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

Here is a [typical example](http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson24.htm) for creating a DAO recordset:

```
Private Sub OpenOneRecordset()

        Dim dbExercise As DAO.Database
        Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset

        Set dbExercise = CurrentDb
        Set rsEmployees = dbExercise.OpenRecordset("Employees")

        dbExercise.Close
        Set dbExercise = Nothing

End Sub
```

I want to create multiple recordsets, one for each name as found in an array:

```
Public Sub OpenAllRecordsets()

    Dim dbExercise As DAO.Database
    Set dbExercise = CurrentDb

    For Each varTable In arrTables

        strRecordsetName = "rst" & varTable

        ''Above is a string...
        ''How can I use the string to declare this object?

        ''  !!!!!!!!! OBVIOUSLY THIS WON'T WORK...
        Dim strRecordsetName As DAO.Recordset
        Set strRecordsetName = dbExercise.OpenRecordset(varTable)

    Next

    dbExercise.Close
    Set dbExercise = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can't see how to declare the name dynamically, then use that to make a recordset.  I would think this is handled similar to `TableDefs`, where I call up the collection and add a member.  Do you think?

### UPDATE following the first posted Answer:

I'm using these recordsets in a recursive function.  It works, but I want to reduce run-time.  I have been recreating each recordset for the needed new record.

```
If nodeThis.hasChildNodes Then

    strTable = nodeThis.parentNode.nodeName

    Dim rsNewChild As DAO.Recordset         ' ***
    Set rsNewChild = cnn.OpenRecordset(strTable, dbOpenDynaset)  ' ***

    rsNewChild.AddNew

    '' ...populate fields
    For Each ...
        strName = nodeThis.nodeName            
        rsNewChild(strName) = nodeThis.Text
    Next

    rsNewChild.Update

    rsNewChild.close             ' ***
    Set rsNewChild = Nothing     ' ***

End If
```

But I know what recordsets are needed, so I'd rather open them all at the start and then call as needed.  That would let me remove the lines marked `***`.  The issue then is how to use a string (available in the function) to call out a given recordset.

To re-state the goal more correctly and helpfully: I need to take a string and use it to invoke the needed recordset:

```
[ BASED ON STRING ].AddNew
```

For Barranka's solution, I'm concerned about the resources for looping through that array for every call.  But I'll give it a try, do some testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as `TableDefs` is a built-in `Collection` of `TableDef` objects, you can create your own `Collection` of `Recordset` objects  and refer to them by name like so:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, myRecordsets As Collection
Dim testArray(1) As String, tblName As Variant

' test data
testArray(0) = "People"
testArray(1) = "OtherPeople"

' build the collection
Set myRecordsets = New Collection
Set cdb = CurrentDb
For Each tblName In testArray
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset(tblName, dbOpenTable)
    myRecordsets.Add rst, tblName
    Set rst = Nothing
Next

' use the members of the collection
Debug.Print myRecordsets("People").Fields("LastName").Value
myRecordsets("People").MoveNext
Debug.Print myRecordsets("People").Fields("LastName").Value
Debug.Print myRecordsets("OtherPeople").Fields("LastName").Value

Set myRecordsets = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

(Note that the parameters to the `.Add` method of the `Collections` object are `value, key`, which is the opposite of the way `Dictionary` and other associative arrays tend to order their arguments when adding a new entry.)

**Edit re: update to question**

This works, too

```vbs
' add a new record
myRecordsets("OtherPeople").AddNew
myRecordsets("OtherPeople").Fields("LastName").Value = "NewPerson"
myRecordsets("OtherPeople").Update
```

Comment: Nice.  Were you able to find a way to get Intellisense to show recordset methods and properties following `myRecordsets("People").`?

Comment: @HansUp Under VBA I don't think IntelliSense is an option because a VBA `Collection` is a collection of arbitrary objects. AFAIK there is no way to type the values (or keys) as in VB.NET where we could use `Dim myRecordsets As New Dictionary(Of String, Recordset)`.

Comment: It is such a privilege to receive read-to-go test code.  Copy, Paste, Run.

Comment: @HansUp , you *could* get Intellisense to show the members of the underlying object by writing a custom collection class. This class would have to be a wrapper around the `Collection` object, manipulated in a text editor to allow a default member, in this case the Collection's `Item` property re-cast as a `Recordset` object. It's a lot of hassle though!

Answer (score 2):

I would create an array of recordsets:

```
dim rs() as DAO.Recordset
' You must redim the array with something like: ReDim rs(1 to UBound(arrTables))
dim i as Integer
' ...
i = 1
for each varTable in arrTables
    Set rs(i) = dbExcercise.openRecordset(varTable)
    i = i + 1;
next varTable
```

Comment: Sounds pretty good.  In order to add a record to a particular recordset, do I have to loop through all members and check my name against `rs(i).Name`?  I'm pretty sure that is what a VBA array generally requires...but do you know of a shortcut?

Comment: It's a runtime speed concern.  I have many write operations.  If I can define a recordset independently instead of running a loop to get to the needed recordset, that seems more efficient.

Comment: Instead of an array, consider a Collection or Dictionary to hold the recordsets with the table name as the key.  Then you can directly reference any specific recordset via its table name key.

Comment: Takea look [here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s239/collections.htm) for info about collections... I've never used them myself, but it seems like a good idea